# Confusion between moles and molarity units

Tags: concentration, mole, units

I am a total newbie in the field and i would like some kind of guidance.

So, I have been recently given 2 datasets with measurements regarding several phospholipid fatty acids of plasma HDL. Both datasets consist of the same classes of FAs but with different units of measurement (μΜ and mol%).

Since I have no previous experience with that kind of data, can someone give me a hint about how (and if) it is possible to convert from one unit to the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it will be possible as $M$ is $mol dm^{-3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ce{M}$ is a shortcut for $\frac{\ce{mol}}{\ce{l}}$. $\ce{mol}\%$ on the other side is defined as $\frac{n}{n_{\ce{tot}}}$. In order to convert between the two you need to know the density $\rho$ and the molar mass $M$ (don't confuse this with the unit) of your solution/mixture. You can then do
$$
c_{\ce{mol}\%} = \frac{c_\ce{M} \cdot V_{\ce{mix}}}{V_{\ce{mix}} \cdot \rho \cdot M^{-1}} = \frac{c_\ce{M}}{\rho \cdot M^{-1}}
$$
$c_{\ce{mol}\%}$ is the concentration in $\ce{mol}\%$ and $c_M$ the one in $\ce{M}$.